# Potential energy of a one-dimensional mass

Tags: potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, approximations

> The potential energy of a one-dimensional mass $m$ at a distance $r$ from the origin is $$U(r) = U_0 \left(\frac{r}{R} + \lambda^2\frac{R}{r} \right)$$ for $0 < r < \infty$, with $U_0$, $R$, $\lambda$ all positive constants. Find the equilibrium position $r_0$. Let $x$ be the distance from equilibrium and show that, for small $x$, the potential energy has the form $U = \text{const} + \frac{1}{2}kx^2$. What is the angular frequency of small oscillations?

Here is a problem that I have encountered in a textbook. How do I solve this?

My attempt:
Substitute $r=r_0$ and $U(r)=U_0$
$U_0 = U_0\left(\frac{r_0}{R} + \lambda^2\frac{R}{r_0} \right)$
$\frac{1}{R}{r_0}^2 - r_0 + \lambda^2 R = 0$
$r_0=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}{2/R}$
This does not match up with the answer key, which says that $r_0 = \lambda R$.

Proceeding onto the second part involving potential energy (using the answer provided):
$U(r)-U(r_0)$
$=U_0\left(\frac{r}{R} + \lambda^2\frac{R}{r}-\frac{r_0}{R}-\frac{\lambda^2R}{r_0} \right)$
$=U_0 \left( \frac{r}{R} + \lambda^2 \frac{R}{r} - 2 \lambda \right)$ using the answer provided earlier
$=\frac{U_0}{Rr}(r^2 + \lambda^2R^2 -2\lambda Rr)$
$=\frac{U_0}{Rr}x^2$ since $x=r-r_0=r-\lambda R$
and thus
$U(r)$
$= U(r_0) + \frac{U_0}{Rr}x^2$
$\approx U(r_0) + \frac{U_0}{Rr_0}x^2$ because small $x$ implies $r \approx r_0$
$= U(r_0) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{2U_0}{\lambda R^2}x^2$
so $k=\frac{2U_0}{\lambda R^2}$ and thus $w=\sqrt{\frac{2U_0}{m\lambda R^2}}$ which matches the answer provided.

**How do I solve the first part involving the equilibrium position?

Are there any flaws in my attempt for the second part involving the potential energy?**

Comment: The equilibrium ist at the minimum of U(r), why should it be at U(r)=U0?

Comment: the equilibrium position is where the force equal zero, the force is $~F=-\frac{d}{dr}\,U(r)=0~$ you obtain $~r=\pm\lambda\,R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find extrema of the potential energy at positions $r_0$ by differentiating it with respect to r and setting it equal to zero: $\frac{d}{dr}U(r)|_{r=r_0}=0$. We find
$$
\frac{d}{dr}U(r)=U_0(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{\lambda^2}{r^2}R)
$$

Thus, by rearranging, we get $r_0=\pm\lambda R$. Since we are told that $0<r<\infty$, we find that the equilibrium position is $r_0=\lambda R$.

Answer (score 0):

The second part can also be solved easily by using Taylor's expansion.
$U\left(r\right)$ about $r_0$ is

$$U\left(r_0\right)+\left(r-r_0\right)\frac{\mathrm d\ }{\mathrm dx}U\left(r_0\right)+\left(r-r_0\right)^2\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}U\left(r_0\right)+\cdots  \tag1$$

Since $x$ is very small, we neglect higher orders.

Notice that the second term is zero, because we know that at $r_0$, the potential energy is at equilibrium. The second derivative at $r_0$ is constant, and since $x=r-r_0$ we get,

$$U\left(x\right)=C+\frac12kx^2\tag2$$

where $C$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

with

$$U(r)=U_0\left(\underbrace{\frac rR+\lambda^2\frac Rr}_{w(r)}\right)$$

the force is

$$F(r)=-\frac {d}{dr}\,U(r)=-\frac {d}{dr}\,U_0(~w(r)~)\,\frac{dw}{dr}=
-\frac {d}{dr}\,U_0(~w(r)~)\,\left(\frac 1R-\lambda^2\frac{R}{r^2}\right)$$

for static equilibrium the force is equal zero

$$F(r)=0\quad\Rightarrow \frac{dw}{dr}=0\quad
\Rightarrow r=\pm\lambda\,R$$

take the force at $~r=\lambda\,R+x~$ you obtain

$$F(\lambda\,R+x)=-\frac {d}{dr}\,U(r)\bigg|_{r=\lambda\,R+x}\,\left(\frac 1R-\lambda^2\frac{R}{(\lambda\,R+x)^2}\right)$$

linearize the force $~F(x)~$ at $~x=0~$  $~~(F(x=0)=F( \lambda\,R)=0)~$

$$F_L=k\,x+...\quad\Rightarrow U=\int F_L(x)\,dx=\text{constant}+\frac 12\,k\,x^2$$

thus the potential